# Text cursor freezing, jumping

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, mouse, cursor

Sometimes the text cursor stops flashing, and when I type nothing shows up. Then I click the mouse, and suddenly everything I just typed appears, and the cursor's frozen at a new location.

When I click inside the white area of the scroll bar, the page jumps and the cursor starts flashing again. Problem solved temporarily.

This started when I upgraded from 10.5 Leopard to 10.6 Snow Leopard. The answer to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27198/text-input-trouble-on-os-x-snow-leopard-text-doesnt-show-up-before-mouse-clic) suggested that it was a mechanical issue with the mouse. For me it isn't, since I'm using the built-in trackpad.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like it's struggling for memory. What RAM do you have in there & what apps do you have open? Safari or Chrome with a lot of tabs open will eat RAM.

Comment: 4GB RAM. The problem still seems to happen even when the RAM isn't near-full, though. And it's different from general slowness, it's more about "jumpy" behavior.

Comment: Sometimes I have lots of browser tabs open, but other times it's just a text editor or word processor.

Comment: still sounds like it needs that time to page memory, to me.

Comment: Maybe so. On the other hand, it only happens in one application at a time (if I switch to other applications they aren't affected).

Comment: Still, I'll pay closer attention to keeping RAM usage down and see if that helps.